# Select row with most recent date by group in R from sql

Tags: r, sql-server, date

I want to import data from SQL server into R. I have multiple entry ID for different Dates. I need only active observations (i.e. 'endDate'<'lastUpdate') and for other ones I need only  most recent observation for each ID. I wright following code:

```
df <- dt %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      slice(which.max(as.Date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
      select(1:13) %>%
      collect()
```

where `dt=tbl(con, database)`
though I get following error:

> "Error: slice() is not suppoted on database backends"

how can handle this problem: how import data in such stucture?

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks it is better to use `filter`

```
dt %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      filter(max(date) == date)
      ...
```